# Returning Child IDs using JAXRS

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs

I am running into an issue with JAXRS / JAXB including child IDs in JSON results when using @Produces.  Below are portions of my code.  Since we are using Hibernate, I'm abstracting the id into an AbstractEntity class.

POJOs:

```
@XmlRootElement
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    private Serializable id;

    @XmlElement(type-Object.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name="anySimpleType")
    public final Serializable getId() {
      return this.id
    }

    public final Serializable setId(Serializable id) {
      this.id = id;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Parent extends AbstractEntity {
    private String parentName;
    private Child child;

    @XmlElement
    public String getParentName() {
       return parentName;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public Child getChild() {
       return child;
    }

}

@XmlRootElement
public class Child extends AbstractEntity {

    private String childName;

    @XmlElement
    public String getChildName() {
       return childName;
    }

}
```

JAXRS Services:

```
@Path("/parent")
public class ParentService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION.JSON)
    public Parent getById(@PathParam("id") Long id) {

        Parent parent = hibernateDataController.getParentById(id);

        if (parent== null)
           throw new NotFoundException("GET: Parent" + id + " not found.");

        return parent;

     }
}

@Path("/child")
public class ChildService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION.JSON)
    public Child getById(@PathParam("id") Long id) {

        Child child = hibernateDataController.getChildById(id);

        if (child == null)
           throw new NotFoundException("GET: Child " + id + " not found.");

        return child;

     }
}
```

(Note: There is more code not shown, but the main parts are above)

My project is in Eclipse, using Maven, so I fire up Jetty: mvn jetty:run

This is where the problem starts.  I can access the child POJO using:

http://myserver:8080/example/child/get/1   returns->

```
{
    "id":{"@type":"xs:long","$":"1"},
    "childName":"Bart Simpson"
}
```

But, when I access the parent POJO, the id of the child POJO is not returned:

http://myserver:8080/example/parent/get/1    returns ->

```
{
    "id":{"@type":"xs:long","$":"1"},
    "parentName":"Homer Simpson",
    "child": {
        "childName":"BartSimpson"
    }
}
```

Notice that the ID of the child is not returned, just the childName.  The GUI team that I am working with is using GWT and they are requesting that I include the ID of any children in the JSON results.

Any help in getting JAXRS / JAXB to return the ID within the child JSON would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

Matt

Comment: If possible you could make your `id` property more specific than `Serializable` like `long`, this would eliminate the `type` (really xsi:type) attribute from being written out.

Comment: Unfortunately our data model is a bit 'messed up'.  Some of our tables use Long for ID, others use a UUID.  I chose Serializable since it covered both the Long and UUID.  I still wanted one DAO Controller to handle all the tables.

Comment: Your `ParentService` is returning a `Person`. Is there another level in your hierarchy or just a typo when converting to your SO question?

Comment: Bamana - yes, cut and paste error, my apologies, that should be Parent, not Person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution to the missing child IDs this morning.  It actually was not a JAXRS / JAXB issue, but caused by the Hibernate mapping files (yes, I still like to use a mapping file over annotations for Hibernate).

The Hibernate mapping file for the example file above would be:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mycompany.Parent" table="PARENT">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="PARENT_ID" scale="0" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="parentName" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="PARENT_NAME" />
    </property>
    <set name="children" inverse="true" lazy="true" table="CHILD" fetch="select">
        <key>
        <column name="CHILD_ID" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.mycompany.Child" />
    </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.mycompany.Child" table="CHILD">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <column name="CHILD_ID" scale="0" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="childName" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="CHILD_NAME" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="parent" type="com.mycompany.Child" fetch="select">
        <column name="PARENT_ID" />
    </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The fix was to force Hibernate not to 'lazy load' the children.  I changed:

```
<set name="children" inverse="true" **lazy="true"** table="CHILD" **fetch="select"**>
```

to:

```
<set name="children" inverse="true" lazy="false" table="CHILD" **fetch="join"**>
```

With the modified hibernate mapping files, the IDs came through the results of JAXRS:

```
{
    "id":{"@type":"xs:long","$":"1"},
    "parentName":"Homer Simpson",
    "child": {
        "id":{"@type":"xs:long","$":"1"},
        "childName":"BartSimpson"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps if someone else runs into this issue.